# cual es la solucion para no salirme de la consola sql?

Tags: sql, consola

cuando entro a la consola de comandos me genera una salida cuando doy enter para iniciar sin contraseña yme saca del programa de la consola que puedo hacer?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Poner la contraseña?

Comment: no tiene contraseña es que cuando le doy enter me saca del sistema de la consola